# Wrong dd command on main drive - How to recover data?

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, dd

Okay, something annoyingly stupid happened. I wanted to copy an Arch Linux ISO file to my USB thumb drive, but was in a rush, and accidentally entered my main drive as the `of` parameter.

Here are the details:

```
$ sudo dd bs=4MB if=archlinux-2017.08.01-x86_64.iso of=/dev/nvme1n1
```

`/dev/nvme1n1` should have been `/dev/sdb`.

My main drive `/dev/nvme1n1` contained two partitions:

- One 512 MB EFI boot partition
- One ext4 partition spanning the rest of the 1 TB drive

The file size of `archlinux-2017.08.01-x86_64.iso` is 541065216 bytes, or **516 MB**

The computer is still running and appears to be working fine, and I have the output of `lsblk` and `df -h` *before* running the `dd` command. The output is *exactly the same* as when I run the commands now. I assume because the data is cached:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1     259:5    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:6    0   512M  0 part /boot
└─nvme1n1p2 259:7    0   931G  0 part /

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1p2  916G   22G  848G   3% /
/dev/nvme1n1p1  511M   36M  476M   7% /boot
```

`ls /boot` still prints the directory content (probably cached info), but the file content is damaged, and running `ls /boot/EFI`, or `ls /boot/loader` fills the screen with random characters, including lots of `Input/output error`.

Here is some more info:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 259        5  976762584 nvme1n1
 259        6     524288 nvme1n1p1
 259        7  976237255 nvme1n1p2

$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme1n1
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x282bad86

Device         Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1 *        0 1056767 1056768  516M  0 Empty
/dev/nvme1n1p2        164  131235  131072   64M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Looking at the output of `fdisk`, it's pretty clear that the partition table (and probably all data on the boot partition) was destroyed. It should be a `gpt` disklabel type, and the partition sizes/types are wrong. Unfortunately, because of the ISO file size (516 MB), it also overwrote the first 4 MB of my root partition.

A slightly different output from `gdisk`:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/nvme1n1

# selected GPT when asked "Found valid MBR and GPT. Which do you want to use?"

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: Samsung SSD 960 EVO 1TB                 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): <guid>
Partition table holds up to 248 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 63
First usable sector is 64, last usable sector is 1056704
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1 sectors (512 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   2             164          131235   64.0 MiB    0700  ISOHybrid1
```

A couple of related questions I found:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with
- [Accidentally overwrote wrong disk with dd, how to recover?](https://superuser.com/questions/1044576/accidentally-overwrote-wrong-disk-with-dd-how-to-recover)

I have already installed the `testdisk` utility, which looks promising, but I want to make sure that I perform the correct steps *while the computer is still running*. If I shut it down now, it won't boot up anymore, so here are the questions:

- What is the best way to recover from this situation?
- How do I restore the partition table to the previous form, and how do I recreate the /boot partition? I am running Arch Linux with the latest kernel.
- Is there any way of knowing what was contained (and destroyed?) in the first 4 MB of my root partition?

---

EDIT:
Adding more information and details here based on @WumpusQ.Wumbley's suggestion to run the `dumpe2fs` command.

The basic output (first 50 lines) of `dumpe2fs`: https://pastebin.com/fBuFRQfE

To me it looks pretty normal, even the filesystem magic number (`0xEF53`) is correct.

This is followed by `Group 0`:

```
Group 0: (Blocks 0-32767) csum 0x9569 [ITABLE_ZEROED]
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-117
  Reserved GDT blocks at 118-1141
  Block bitmap at 1142 (+1142)
  Inode bitmap at 1158 (+1158)
  Inode table at 1174-1685 (+1174)
  21349 free blocks, 8177 free inodes, 2 directories, 8177 unused inodes
  Free blocks: 11419-32767
  Free inodes: 16-8192
```

Which is then followed by LOTS of groups that say `[...]8192 free inodes, 0 directories, 8192 unused inodes [...]` The first group that actually reports some directories is not until `Group 3648`, or around 25,000 lines later:

```
Group 3648: (Blocks 119537664-119570431) csum 0xa9ea [ITABLE_ZEROED]
  Block bitmap at 119537664 (+0)
  Inode bitmap at 119537680 (+16)
  Inode table at 119537696-119538207 (+32)
  23930 free blocks, 1670 free inodes, 614 directories, 1670 unused inodes
  Free blocks: 119546502-119570431
  Free inodes: 29890939-29892608
```

There are a lot of backup superblocks throughout the filesystem:

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/nvme1n1p2 | grep -i superblock | wc -l
dumpe2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
19
```

Comment: A possible starting point would be `dumpe2fs /dev/nvme1n1p2`. It would give basic information about the layout of the filesystem, and a list of free blocks

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Thanks! The command outputs a LOT of information. I saved it to an external drive for later reference. Is there anything I should be looking at in particular?

Comment: I'd look for what's in blocks 0-1023 (which would be 4MB assuming normal block size of 4k). The superblock and group descriptors can be recreated, so don't worry about those. What you probably have in that range is a lot of inodes. Next step: save whatever you can from cache by `dd if=/dev/nvme1n1p2 of=/some/external/device bs=4096 count=1024`. After that, boot a rescue disk, and then run the same `dd` in reverse, to put what *was* in cache back on the disk. Then it's repair time... you have the option of using automated repair tools but you also have a map to look at for manual recovery.

Comment: I do think you're being wise by trying to recover data before writing anything further.  Is there a reason not to back up all your data?  (Even if you can't attach another drive without shutting down the computer, you can likely to do using networking?)  You might find that the system may become unstable when it tries to use some of that missing data, so sooner may be better.

Comment: @TOOGAM I'm aware the system might become unstable, which is why right now I'm not actively using it. When you say "Is there a reason not to back up all your data?" you mean shut down the system and back up the disk from a recovery medium? The reason why the system is still running is because I want to make sure I extract all the potentially useful data from RAM that might aid in the data recovery later on.

Comment: @friederbluemle : No.  You can back up data while the system is still running.  Back up over the network.  (You'll need a destination to store the data.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the partition table and boot partition can be recreated easily, so I will focus on the ext4 partition.

The layout of the filesystem is somewhat dependent on the options used when creating it. I'll describe the common case. You can see if this matches yours by running `dumpe2fs` on the device (which will hopefully find all of the top-level metadata in cache rather than reading from disk).

The normal block size for ext4 filesystems is 4096 bytes, so you have lost 1024 blocks.

The first thing overwritten was block 0, the primary superblock. This is not a problem by itself, because there are backup superblocks. After that is the group descriptor table, which also has backups within the filesystem.

Then there are block bitmaps and inode bitmaps. This is where the news starts to get slightly worse. If any of these are below block 1024, which they probably are, you've lost information about which inodes and blocks are in use. This information is redundant, and will be reconstructed by fsck based on what it finds traversing all the directories and inodes, if those are intact.

But the next thing is the inode table, and here you've probably lost a lot of inodes, including the root directory, journal, and other special inodes. It will be nice to have those back. Obviously the root directory at least is still functional, or just about all commands you try to run would be failing already.

If you run a `dd if=/dev/nvme1n1p2 of=/some/external/device bs=4096 count=1024` now, you'll get a backup copy of whatever is in your cache currently, mixed with the bad data for the blocks that aren't cached. Then after booting a rescue disk you can do the same `dd` in reverse, to put that partially-good data back on the disk, overwriting the all-bad stuff that's there now.

After this you might find automated recovery tools (`fsck`, `testdisk`) work well enough. If not, you have a map you can use to help with manual recovery. Using the "free block" lists from `dumpe2fs`, you know which blocks to ignore.

Most of what you lost is probably inodes. It's actually fairly likely that you had no file *contents* in the first 4MB of disk. (I ran `mkfs.ext4` with no options on a 1TB image file, and the first non-metdata block turned out to be block 9249)

Every inode you manage to recover will identify the data blocks of a whole file. And those data blocks might be located all over the disk, not necessarily nearby.

### Day 2

The dump posted on pastebin reveals great news:

```
Group 0: (Blocks 0-32767) csum 0x9569 [ITABLE_ZEROED]
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-117
  Reserved GDT blocks at 118-1141
  Block bitmap at 1142 (+1142)
  Inode bitmap at 1158 (+1158)
  Inode table at 1174-1685 (+1174)
  21349 free blocks, 8177 free inodes, 2 directories, 8177 unused inodes
  Free blocks: 11419-32767
  Free inodes: 16-8192
```

Since we think only 4MB at the start of the filesystem have been overwritten, we only need to worry about blocks 0-1023. And the reserved GDT blocks go all the way out to block 1141! This is the kind of damage that should be repaired by a simple `e2fsck -b $backup_superblock_number` (after a reboot). You could at least try that with `-n` to see what it thinks.

Comment: Good explanation, but: *"Then after booting a rescue disk you can do the same dd in reverse, to put that partially-good data back on the disk, overwriting the all-bad stuff that's there now."* seems like a bad advice! Don't overwrite the original disk! `testdisk` etc can work on the image rather than the original disk.

Comment: I find it very unlikely that block data would be cached. As such, `dd`ing the start of the partition won’t do any good. It’ll contain the data that is currently on-disk, which is invalid.

Comment: If `testdisk` can work from a copy of the first 1024 blocks, while referencing the actual disk for the rest, that would be perfect. And this is all based on the hope that reading from the partition will return cached blocks where they exist, instead of what's currently on disk, because the overwrite was to the full-disk device, not the partition. If the cache keeps track of aliasing between the full disk and partition, and unifies the cached blocks, the whole idea won't work. (I think the fact that `dumpe2fs` didn't bomb is a good sign though).

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley This is some great information, thanks for this detailed answer! Quick update on the progress: I used the `dd` command to copy the first 1024 blocks to an external disk. I also looked at the `dumpe2fs` output in more detail and noticed something interesting. I will edit the original question as it won't fit here/won't be formatted nicely.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I just saw your "Day 2" edit. Amazing, your explanation makes total sense, and if it turns out to be true I guess I could call extremely lucky. If the ISO file would have been only slightly larger, those inode tables would be gone as well. Meanwhile, the system is still running, and I copied everything from my home directory to an external disk. Next, I'll attempt Rod Smith's suggestion below: "fix the partition table problem as quickly as possible and then shut down and fix the filesystem problem from an emergency disk". Thanks again!

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I was able to recover everything. Amazing. Just like you said, after recreating the partition table, booting from a live usb, and running `e2fsck` (I used superblock backup at `32768`), the filesystem check fixed A LOT of issues. I was then able to mount my partition, with all data intact. I manually recreated the EFI/boot partition, and the computer boots up fine. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

If the disk used GPT, the partition table should be recoverable by using the backup GPT data at the end of the disk. You can do this with `gdisk`; see [the `gdisk` documentation on data recovery](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) for details. In brief: When you launch `gdisk` on the disk, it will *probably* notice the damage and ask you if you want to use the backup GPT data or the MBR data. If you pick the GPT option and then write the changes, the partition table will be fixed. If `gdisk` does not ask about which partition table to use, you might still be able to load the backup table using the `c` option on the recovery & transformation menu.

If this fails, you could still re-create the partition table (or at least, the partitions' start and end points) by using the data in `/sys/block/nvme1n1/nvme1n1p1/start` and `/sys/block/nvme1n1/nvme1n1p1/size` files (and similarly for `/dev/nvme1n1p2`). If you resort to this data, though, it's imperative that you ***NOT*** shut down the computer, contrary to what hek2mgl advised. That said, hek2mgl is not wrong that continuing to use the disk in its current state runs the risk of making matters worse. Overall, I'd say the best compromise is to try to fix the partition table problem as quickly as possible and then shut down and fix the filesystem problem from an emergency disk.

Unfortunately, your ESP is toast. Given your disk layout, I'm guessing you mounted the ESP at `/boot` and stored your kernels there. Thus, you'll need to re-install your kernel packages using a `chroot` or some other means. Ditto for your boot loader or boot manager.

Comment: Thanks Rod! `gdisk` does output `Found valid MBR and GPT. Which do you want to use?`. When I pick GPT, it tells me: `Using GPT and creating fresh protective MBR.
Warning! Main partition table overlaps the first partition by 64 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
` The info it gives me using `p` is all wrong though. I could try `c` next. Output from `/sys/block` seems correct. Your assumption about ESP mount is also correct.

Comment: Yes, try the `c` option. I don't hold out much hope, though; it sounds like the backup partition table may be damaged. (This would likely have been caused by something other than your accident with `dd`, since that should not have affected the backup partition table.)

Comment: I think you're right, the backup partition table seems to be damaged as well. No matter which table I select (main or backup), the `p` command prints an invalid layout. Does that mean the backup was overwritten by main? How could that be, if it's at the *end* of the disk?

Comment: My guess (and it's only that) is that something else, perhaps a long time ago, damaged the backup partition table. Linux will boot and work correctly with a damaged backup partition table, so you might not have noticed this until now. Your best bet, if you haven't rebooted, is to use the `/sys/block/` data to recover your partitions, as noted in my answer. You can then attempt recovery of the filesystem on the ext4fs partition.

Comment: Thanks again. How exactly would I go about recovering the partitions? Using `fdisk`? Using `gdisk` with the `o` command, then `n`? A different tool?

Answer (score 0):

1. Shutdown the computer (immediately)
2. Boot it with a rescue system.
3. Run `testdisk` to try to recover your data. (If you have enough space, take an image from the device using `dd` and run `testdisk` on that image)

Why should you shutdown the computer immediately? If a new file will be created (something in /run probaly) or appended to (/var/log/...) then the file system needs to look at the existing (bad!) information to decide where to store the data. When this decision is been made based on bad information, the risk is high that existing data blocks will get overwritten. That makes them lost forever. Even for tools like `testdisk` and `photorec`.

Comment: You really think there's no value in the idea of extracting information from the running system? It has potentially useful information in RAM that will be gone forever as soon as it is shut down.

Comment: Which filesystem was on the big partition?

Comment: You may be able to restore the superblock. Check this (I never tried it) https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-filesystem-superblock.html and this (and so on) https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/surviving-a-linux-filesystem-failures.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit hesitant shutting down the computer, as I can still read all (?) data in my home folder (on the big partition) - I could potentially copy the data to an external drive. Once I reboot, I'm pretty sure the partition cannot (easily) be mounted anymore.  As mentioned in the original question, the fs was ext4.

Comment: With any more action on that partition (be it a log file in /var/log etc) you risk to loose more data.